# Why won't my httpModule BeginRequest fire?

Tags: httpmodule

I am using an httpModule in a .NET 4.0 web app to rewrite urls. Locally, this works fine. But moving it out to a host, it simply isn't firing.

I set up the following in the web config...

```
<httpModules>
<add type="PageLoader" name="PageLoader"/>
</httpModules>
```

I also added this as an attempt but it didn't work...

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add type="PageLoader" name="PageLoader" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Type should be of the form

```
"FullyQualifiedTypeName, Namespace ( or DLL Name)"
```

so if your module is:  YourApp.Web.Extensions.HttpModules.MyHttpModule

then the declaration should be:

```
<add name="MyHttpModule" type="YourApp.Web.Extensions.HttpModules.MyHttpModule, YourApp.Web" />
```

Also note that for IIS7 this needs to go into the system.webserver element in Web.config:

```
<system.webserver>
    <add name="MyHttpModule" type="YourApp.Web.Extensions.HttpModules.MyHttpModule, YourApp.Web" />
</system.webserver>
```